# How to disable `h` in `less` for help?

Tags: less

When I press `h` in `less` pager, it displays a help screen. For a seasoned vim/less user, this behavior is extremely annoying. How can I disable the `h` key for showing the help screen in `less`?

```
>>> /bin/less --version
less 458 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2012 Mark Nudelman

less comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
For information about the terms of redistribution,
see the file named README in the less distribution.
Homepage: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use a `lesskey` file to change the key bindings and more `h` and `H` somewhere more to your liking.  From the manual:

> **KEY BINDINGS**
>
> You may define your own `less` commands by using the program `lesskey` (1) to create a `lesskey` file.  This file specifies a set of command keys and an action associated with each key.  You may also use `lesskey` to change the line-editing keys (see **LINE EDITING**), and to set environment variables.  If the environment variable `LESSKEY` is set, `less` uses that as the name of the `lesskey` file.
>   Otherwise, `less` looks in a standard place for the lesskey file: On Unix systems, less looks for a `lesskey` file called `$HOME/.less`.  On MS-DOS and Windows systems, less  looks  for  a `lesskey` file  called `$HOME/_less`, and if it is not found there, then looks for a `lesskey` file called `_less` in any directory specified in the `PATH` environment variable.  On OS/2 systems, less looks for a `lesskey` file called `$HOME/less.ini`, and if it is not found, then looks for a `lesskey` file called `less.ini` in any directory specified in the `INIT` environment variable, and if it [is] not found there, then looks for a `lesskey` file called `less.ini` in any directory specified in the `PATH` environment variable.  See the `lesskey` manual page for more details.
>
> A  system-wide `lesskey` file may also be set up to provide key bindings.  If a key is defined in both a local `lesskey` file and in the system-wide file, key bindings in the local file take precedence over those in the system-wide file.  If the environment variable `LESSKEY_SYSTEM` is set, less uses that as the name of the system-wide lesskey file.  Otherwise, less looks  in  a  standard place  for  the  system-wide  lesskey  file:  On  Unix  systems,  the  system-wide  lesskey  file is `/usr/local/etc/sysless`.  (However, if less was built with a different `sysconf` directory than `/usr/local/etc`, that directory is where the `sysless` file is found.)  On MS-DOS and Windows systems, the system-wide `lesskey` file is `c:\_sysless`.  On OS/2 systems, the system-wide  `lesskey` file is `c:\sysless.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in a program called [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager).

You may also be interested in this very similar question on the Super User Stack Exchange: [How to use my vim configuration in less?](https://superuser.com/questions/575808/how-to-use-my-vim-configuration-in-less), which describes `vimpager` and other solutions you might like.

Since you want regular vim keybindings, you'll want to use the `let g:less.enabled = 0` setting in your `.vimrc` or `.vimpagerrc`.  Otherwise, it will use `less` bindings!